# Conflicto entre pack y grid al lanzar ventana secundaria desde ventana principal

Tags: python, tkinter

```
class App:
    ##CONEXION A BASE DE DATOS SQLITE3##
    db_name = 'database.db'


    def __init__(self, window):
        ##VENTANA PRINCIPAL##
        self.wind = window
        self.wind.title("ABMC")
        self.wind.geometry('250x200')

        ##AGREGO CONTENEDOR 1##

        contenedor = LabelFrame(self.wind, text='Registre neuvo producto', borderwidth=2, relief = RAISED)
        contenedor.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, pady=20)
        contenedor.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

        ## PRODUCTO##
        Label(contenedor, text="Producto: ").grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.producto = Entry(contenedor)
        self.producto.focus()
        self.producto.grid(row=1, column=1)

        ## PRECIO ##
        Label(contenedor, text='Precio: ').grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.precio = Entry(contenedor)
        self.precio.grid(row=2, column=1)

        ## MENSAJE LABEL##
        self.mensaje = Label(contenedor, text="", fg="red")
        self.mensaje.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=4)


        ##AGREGO CONTENEDOR 2
        self.contenedor2 = Frame(self.wind)
        self.contenedor2.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

        ##CONTROLES##
        self.seccion_controles = Frame(self.contenedor2, borderwidth=2)
        self.seccion_controles.pack(side=TOP, expand=NO, fill=BOTH, padx=7, pady=7)
        Label(self.seccion_controles, text="Controles", bg="#222", fg="White",
        justify=LEFT).pack(side=TOP, expand=NO, fill=X, anchor=W)
        self.controles = Frame(self.seccion_controles, bg="#222")
        self.controles.pack(side=TOP, expand=NO, fill=X)

        boton1 = Button(self.seccion_controles, text='Guardar Datos', command=self.agregar_producto)
        boton2 = Button(self.seccion_controles, text='Modifica Datos', command=self.emergente)
        boton1.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill=BOTH)
        boton2.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill=BOTH)


        ##CERRAR APLICACION##
        self.seccion_cerrar = Frame(self.contenedor2, height=22, borderwidth=2, relief=RAISED)
        self.seccion_cerrar.pack(side=BOTTOM, expand=NO, fill=X, padx=7)
        self.cerrar = Frame(self.seccion_cerrar, bg="#222", height=22)
        self.cerrar.pack(side=TOP, expand=NO, fill=X)
        Cerrar(self.seccion_cerrar)


    #############################################LOGICA####################################################
    #############################################LOGICA####################################################


    def run_consulta(self, consulta, parameters =()):
         with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
             cursor = conn.cursor()
             result = cursor.execute(consulta, parameters)
             conn.commit()
         return result



    def validacion(self):
        return len(self.producto.get()) !=0 and len(self.precio.get()) != 0

    def agregar_producto(self):
        if self.validacion():
            consulta = 'INSERT INTO product VALUES (NULL, ?, ?)'
            parametros = (self.producto.get(), self.precio.get())
            self.run_consulta(consulta, parametros)
            self.mensaje['text'] = 'Producto {} agregado correctamente'.format(self.producto.get())
            self.producto.delete(0, END)
            self.precio.delete(0, END)
        else:
            self.mensaje['text'] = 'Agregue un producto y precio'




    def emergente(self):
        from modifica_borra import edicion
        t= Toplevel()
        edicion(t)
```

Necesito que el botón <kbd>Modifica Dato</kbd> me
traiga la clase `edición` dentro de `modifica_borra.py`.  La función que hice abajo emergente es lo mas próximo a traer la clase que estuve, sin embargo me devuelve una ventana en blanco, con el titulo correspondiente, y me tira un mensaje de error como el siguiente:

> ```
> File "C:/Users/Lucas/Desktop/CRUD2/main.py", line 102, in emergente
>     edicion(t)
> File "C:\Users\Lucas\Desktop\CRUD2\modifica_borra.py", line 19, in __init__
>     self.formulario.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2226, in grid_configure
>     + self._options(cnf, kw))
> _tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack
> ```

Si alguien puede ayudarme, se los agradezco enormemente, estoy con esto hace una semana leyendo y leyendo y no puedo encontrar la solución, cabe destacar que en el otro `.py` tengo un `treeview`, botones y demás cosas.

---

### Edición

Dejo el inicializador de la clase `edicion`:

```
class edicion:
    def __init__(self, ventana=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, ventana)
        self.ventana = ventana
        self.ventana.title("Modifica y Borra")

        ##GRILLA##
        self.formulario = ttk.Treeview(height = 7, columns = 2)
        self.formulario.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

        self.formulario.heading('#0', text = 'Producto', anchor = CENTER)
        self.formulario.heading('#1', text = 'Precio', anchor = CENTER)

        ## MENSAJE LABEL##
        self.mensaje = Label(text = "", fg = "red")
        self.mensaje.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=4)

        ##CONTENEDOR##
        self.container = LabelFrame(self.ventana)
        self.container.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3)
        boton1 = ttk.Button(self.container, text='Ver Datos', 
        command=self.show_productos)
        boton2 = ttk.Button(self.container, text='Modifica Datos', 
        command=self.editar)
        boton3 = ttk.Button(self.container, text='Borra Datos', 
        command=self.borrar_producto)
        boton1.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill=BOTH)
        boton2.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill=BOTH)
        boton3.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill=BOTH)


        self.format_grilla()
```

Comment: Ok, entiendo, entonces, como podría hacer para llamar esa clase con mi botón modifica datos? o no hay manera de poder llamar un grid ??

Comment: Mira, te pase otra parte del codigo que me deja correr todo en simultaneo, osea tengo 2 ventanas, pero una no me deja llamar a la otra

Comment: Sos un groso !!! MILES DE MILLONES DE GRACIAS !!!

Comment: De nada Andrés,  he agregado una respuesta explicando el problema mejor y con un ejemplo mínimo. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

El error se debe a la unión de dos problemas:

- Los administradores de geometría `pack` y `grid` son excluyentes dentro de un mismo contenedor padre. No tiene sentido intentar usarlos juntos porque por su propias características tkinter se pasaría la eternidad intentando negociar una solución que complazca a ambos administradores.
- Siempre se debería pasar de forma explícita, como primer argumento del inicializador de la clase, a todo widget que se instancia una referencia al contenedor padre.

  De no hacer esto, el widget se posiciona siempre en la ventana principal de la aplicación a la que pertenezca, es decir, a la instancia de Tk cuyo mainloop maneja ese widget.

Podemos simplificar tu código de la siguiente manera:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Secundaria:
    def __init__(self, ventana=None):
        label = tk.Label(text="Ventana secundaria")
        label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        frame = tk.Frame()
        frame.grid(row=1, column=0)
        tk.Button(frame, text="Púlsame")

def abrir_secundaria():
    ventana = tk.Toplevel()
    Secundaria(ventana)


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x100")
btn = tk.Button(root, text="Abrir secundaria", command=abrir_secundaria)
btn.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Cuando pulsamos el botón se muestra la ventana secundaria vacía (resultado de `ventana = tk.Toplevel()`) pero falla la sustanciación de `Secundaria`:

> ```
> Secundaria(ventana)
>   File "temp.py", line 10, in __init__
>     label.grid(row=0, column=0)
>   File ".pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2223, in grid_configure
>     + self._options(cnf, kw))
> _tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack
> ```

El problema es que **no se especifica el padre de `label` y `frame` de `Secundaria`**, como `Toplevel` se ejecuta bajo el mainloop de la ventana principal, los widgets intenta dibujarse en`root` (ventana principal) y no en  `ventana` (`Toplevel`). Como `root` usa `pack` para posicionar el botón que lanza la ventana secundaria al intentar usar `grid` para poscionar `frame` y `label` tenemos la excepción.

La solución es tan simple como pasar `self.ventana` como padre de ambos widgets:

```
class Secundaria:
    def __init__(self, ventana=None):
        label = tk.Label(ventana, text="Ventana secundaria")
        label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        frame = tk.Frame(ventana)
        frame.grid(row=1, column=0)
        tk.Button(frame, text="Púlsame").pack()
```

En tu caso concreto sería:

```
self.formulario = ttk.Treeview(self.ventana, height=7, columns=2)
self.mensaje = Label(self.ventana, text = "", fg = "red")
```

Hay que observar que aunque en Secundaria se usa `pack` y `grid` conjuntamente no es un problema. Esto se debe a que no entran en conflicto al estar en contendores distintos. De hecho, usar `Frames` anidados o recurrir a `place` es una forma de lidiar con exclusión mutua de `pack` y `grid`.

Comment: Excelente !! Ayer lo pude resolver sin ningun problema !! Saludos y muchas gracias !!